# Entity Framework Check for references before deleting

Tags: reference, entity-framework-4, constraints

Say I have a User that I want to delete, but the User might be referenced by other tables in the database. Is there a way to check for references to this user before trying to delete or is the best option to just delete and catch/handle the exception that `SaveChanges()` throws?

Obviously I could check each table where the user *might* be referenced...but I would rather not as it is referenced in a few places and it just seems like a messy way to do things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't now if you have found a solution to this yet but I'm posting since i run into a similar problem myself. I suppose you could use a query to check for references lets say something like..

```
bool related = db.Article.Where(i => i.CategoryId == id).Any();
```

But i believe it is better to catch the exception than to check for references.

For scenarios where you want a required relationship but no cascade delete you
can explicitly override the convention and configure cascade delete behavior with the
Fluent API.
The Fluent API method to use is called **WillCascadeOnDelete** and takes a Boolean as a
parameter. This configuration is applied to a relationship, which means that you first
need to specify the relationship using a Has/With pairing and then call WillCascadeOn
Delete. Something like:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Article>()
            .HasRequired(a => a.Category)
            .WithMany(i => i.Articles)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Then you usually get a DbUpdateException or a InvalidOperationException depending on how your data is loaded into memory. You can catch them with a simple statement and add a message to the user.

```
try
{
  db.Category.Remove(category);
  db.SaveChanges();
  return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
catch (DataException)
{
ModelState.AddModelError("", "Your message here");
return View(category);
}
```

What WillCascadeOnDelete basically does is that it changes the Delete rule in your database from **Cascade** to **No Action** which causes the error to be thrown when a violation occurs.
The overall message here is that you have control over the cascade delete setting, but
you will be responsible for avoiding or resolving possible conflicts caused by
not having a cascade delete present. It worked for me, hope it helps you too.
See also:[Configuring Relationships with the Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591620)

Comment: Great explanation, thanks. I did end up going with the "catch-the-error" solution as it seemed like the neatest way of handling things.